# Is it bad practice to redirect an image through a script?

Tags: php, html, image

Is it bad to do this?

**index.php**

`<img src = "image.php"/>`

**image.php**

```
header('location: /location/to/another/image.jpg');
```

You're probably looking at this thinking "why the hell does he want to do this". Above is just a simple scenario of what I'm doing, I just want to know if it's "acceptable" to do this?

Comment: As long as it works, it's acceptable :) Whether this is clean code is a different matter.

Comment: Having a hard time articulating reasons for or against it.

Comment: Why don't you just load the `/location/to/another/image.jpg` inside `image.php`?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to do this?

Comment: Because I need to put a string on the end for cache reason ?id=438208 which can only be done inside the file not in the html code.

Comment: In that case maybe have the page put the string rather then a redirecting url? Or use the no cache header...

Comment: Also i dont think the string there for cache reasons would work. It would just look at the url, remember that it visited it and use the OLD result. You either need it on the page or set the no cache header

Answer (score 4):

Sure, you can do that, but you might note that PHP can also just return the bytes of the image and the appropriate headers (content type, etc); if what you are after is simply to have your image requests "parsed" by PHP. So your image.php request can be the only request.

See the example script on [PHP's doc page for fpassthru](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.fpassthru.php#example-2236)

Comment: I rather send the server a command via headers to serve an image rather then processing it through php but thats a fair answer. +1

Answer (score 1):

Its not terrible but most recommendations are not to have links/urls redirect when you don't need to as it will slow down page loading (its like doing two pings instead of one multiplied by each image)

Also its suggested to configure your webserver to do something like that. I use nginx and i have done that for one portion of one site (it confirms the user is signed in to see their unpublished files). But this is using the x-accel-redirect header which isnt a real redirect but simply tells the server it should serve that particular file.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how many users access this page. As *acidzombie24* mentioned, such a redirect will slow down your server. But when your server is configured properly and `Connection: keep-alive` is supported, it will not need a second connection but only a second request in the same connection.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you're trying to prevent the browser from caching these images by appending a unique ID at the end of the URL.

When you redirect, you'll telling the browser in the headers to forget about this request and initiate a request to another URL, so you'll be getting two requests for every one image request.

Instead of forcing the browser to redirect in `image.php`, you can just load the image file, and it'll have the same affect as redirecting the browser (i.e. no cache), but without the requiring another request.

In HTML:

```
<img src="image.php?id=whatever" />
```

In `image.php`:

```
readfile( 'location/to/another/image.jpg'); // local file system path needed
```

Done. No caching by the browser, and no additional overhead of another request.